# Google analytics returning user definition when filtered by campaign

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics, web-analytics

I have a campaign link setup by the url builder with campaign codes and I want to know how many users return if their first touch to the site is by the campaign URL while their return visits could be through any channel.

If i did a segmentation to filter on my campaign code and then set the dimension to be user type (new vs returning users):

- will the returning users number equal to  users who first came in
  through that code regardless of the channel they came in on their
  subsequent visit?
- Or does the returning users equal to users who came in by
  clicking on my campaign link again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segments represent either subsets of sessions or subsets of users. In your case, your isolating your data to all sessions originating from your campaign.

So the returning users wil be equal to users who first came in through that code regardless of the channel they came in on their subsequent visit.